# scheduling different crontimers with the same job id

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

how to schedule the different timings for same job.

For ex: I have a job(asssume job name is = "job1")

the job1 have diff timers(`20 * * * * ?`) and (`0 0/2 * * * ?`)

First timer need to schedule every 20 seconds and second timer need to schedule every 2 minutes.

My problem is the last timer only scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

You could only set it to 20 seconds. This way, on the 6th trigger you would have the 2 minutes triggering. Or was that just an example ?

Otherwise, AFAIK, you would need to create two instances.

Comment: that is just an example i want to run different timers for same job.

Fir Detailed Example: one timer is (0 35 10 * * ?) and (0 38 10 * * ?) and (0 40 10 * * ?) 
in those above 3 timers only the last one 10.40 AM is only scheduling the remaining two is not scheduling

Comment: You should then create distinct instances for each trigger expression that cannot be triggered by the lowest common divisor timeout.